# How to diff pom.xml files and programmatically ignore changes related to snapshot vs release versions?

Tags: git, maven

For example, lets say I have a pom file on development that looks like this:

```
<project xmlns=blah>
   <version>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
      <!-- testing upgrade of cool oss tool -->
      <version.oss.some.cool.tool>2.5.3</version.oss.some.cool.tool>
      <version.my.junk>0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </properties>
</project>
```

On master, it looks like this

```
<project xmlns=blah>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
   <properties>
      <version.oss.some.cool.tool>2.5.1</version.oss.some.cool.tool>
      <version.my.junk>2.33.1</version>
   </properties>
</project>
```

If I just git diff development and master (or a regular diff between copies of the two files),
the results will show me more than I really want to know. The changes that I want to see are the added comment and the version change for version.oss.some.cool.tool. I do NOT want to see the diffs resulting from 0-SNAPSHOT being replaced with a release version; I expect those to differ between the two branches.

Let's pretend that I cannot simply check if there are commits on development which are not on master or vice versa. In a past life, for a similar situation, I've run the diff output through a filter that stripped out the 'noise' and counted the number of lines left to see if the file changed. That was ugly and fragile. I'd like a better solution. Is there a mvn or git command that will accomplish this trivially that I just don't know about?

Similarly, if both files were identical except for the snapshot vs release, then I would want that diff to say they were identical.

And of course, this needs to be done programmatically because there are oodles and oodles of these files.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why do you use versions like `0-SNAPSHOT`? I don't understand what a `0-SNAPSHOT` version should be compared to a "real" version.

Comment: Well, I was going to say it was the 'standard maven snapshot version', but looking at https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version, I guess we are not using SNAPSHOT quite right. The most current code is always 0-SNAPSHOT on development. The released code on master is the only code that has a non-zero version. So when comparing master to development, we always see hits like 0-SNAPSHOT changing to 1.2.3 or 2.33.1. So by 'real', I mean 'not 0-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: So should I change my question from "0-SNAPSHOT vs real" to "snapshot vs release" Would that help reduce confusion for everyone else who comes across this question?

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: Changed. Thank you.